# Java concurrency lock terminate thread properly

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, monitor

I have a small app which 'simulates' shared printer system with the following classes.

The monitor that is shared by all the threads has the following methods.
A reentrantlock lock and the next methods.

```
public void lock()
{
    lock.lock();
}



public  void unlock()
{  
    lock.unlock();       
}


    public synchronized void refillPaper() {

    while(FullTray())
    {
        try
        {
            this.unlock();
            wait(7000);
            this.lock();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){}
    }

    setPaperLevel(getPaperLevel() - 50);

    System.out.println("Printer refiled");


}


public synchronized void print()
{
    while(!CanPrint())
    {   
        try
        {     
            this.unlock();
            wait();
            this.lock();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {}    
    }
     System.out.println(getPaperLevel()); 
}
```

Then the threads : User and Tech

The User thread run method:

```
public void run()
{

    Printer.lock(); // the lock() method using the reentrant lock
    System.out.println(this.getNames() + "locked");
    for( int i = 0; i< 4; i++)
    {     
         Printer.print();
         try
         {
             sleep(1000);
         }
         catch(InterruptedException ex) 
         {}
    }
    Printer.unlock();
    System.out.println(this.getNames + " released");
}
```

And the user Tech thread.

```
public void run()
{
    laserPrinter.lock();
    System.out.println("Paper tech acquired the printer: ");

    for(int i = 0;  i < 3; i++)
    {
        Printer.AddPaper();
        try
        {
            sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {}
    }
    Printer.unlock();
    System.out.println("tech released");
}

ThreadGroup users = new ThreadGroup("Users");
ThreadGroup techs = new ThreadGroup("Techs");

Printer printer = new Printer();
User user1 = new User(users,printer);
User user2 = new User(users,printer);
User user3 = new User(users,printer);
User user4 = new User(users,printer);
Tech tech = new Tech(techs, printer);
```

When a thread locks the printer I'd like it to lock it until the for loop ends.
At the moment I get the following situations:

user calls printer.Print() 4 times if it runs out of paper then the tech thread should lock the monitor and refill paper, but instead of the tech thread the other users thread access it(user1 -> user2(lock no paper? release) -> user3(lock no paper? release) and release until the thread acquires it and refills the paper then nothing happens.

Or if there is enough paper for the users to print if the tech thread is last and the condition is false then it will wait for infinite instead of stopping.

I think I am messing up the way I lock the printer ?

@ Patricia Shananan, badly expressed.
The Printer class is the monitor and provides the Print() and AddPaper() methods.
In the  run() method of the User thread I  call Print() 4 times(using a for loop). In the run() method of the  Tech thread I call the AddPaper() method (for times)

Each time the Print() method is called the paper level is modified.
If the paper is to low then the the monitor should be unlocked. 
Once it is unlocked it usually the monitor is usually acquired by another thread of type User. This will cause the thread that acquired the monitor to release it. This will happen until the monitor is acquired by a thread of type Tech. But after the tech thread is consumed(AddPaper will increase the paperlevel) nothing happens. Shouldnt it go back and run the other threads acquired and released the monitor before they could run the Print() method.

Comment: I am having trouble parsing the paragraphs beginning "user calls" and "or if there is". Please clarify them.

Comment: I would suggest you rethink your whole setup:
your users don't need to be aware of other users at all, 
it's the printer that should provide methods for **any** user to print (maybe implementing it's own printing queue?)
and printer should notify tech thread when it runs out of paper...

Comment: @Germann Arlington the print and refill methods are provided by the Printer class.

Comment: Printer class should expose **only** `print(Document)` and `refillPaper()` methods. You **don't** need to expose `lock()` and `unlock()` methods as they should be used internally by Printer itself, **not** the users

Comment: Ok, but if remove them from the users how do I lock the monitor for the entirety of the threads run method.(for the entire  for loop)